# How can I prevent downstream subscribers of my Flux from executing on any error?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm working on a Reactor project at the moment. One of the cases we have requires going out to a service for each element in a Flux, if any of those fetches fail, we want to fail the whole batch and prevent downstream events from occurring.
Currently the code looks roughly like:

```
getFluxIdsFromDatabase()
  .flatMap(this::fetchFromExternalService)
  .collectList() // prevent downstream execution by having any errors blocked here
  .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable) // back to regularly scheduled Flux if no errors
  .concatMap(this::saveSequentiallyToDatabase)
```

This works... but it really seems to me like I should be able to do this without the switching to a `Mono<List>` just to halt execution on an error. When I try making the first line `concatMap`, I see saves to the database from some elements even though there was an error during the `fetchFromExternalService`. So is there some other Flux method I can call here to do the mapping that will halt everything on an error, or am I stuck with this `collectList`/`flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)` solution?

Comment: In addition to what you already mentioned, you can make your flux optimistic and saveSequentiallyToDatabase but perform a rollback on error. It would be desirable if cases there are fewer failing jobs and it would also be more "reactive".

Comment: Halting execution on an error is something you get by default, but it's that "rollback" behaviour you don't - otherwise you'd have to wait until the *entire* publisher completes before performing the next step, which doesn't really fit the reactive model. Using a database transaction (supported by all major DBs AFAIK) and aborting the transaction on an error, or committing it on complete, would be a much better alternative, IMHO.

Comment: Yeah... I guess in this case I am wanting the entire publisher to complete before performing the next step. The individual elements can complete asynchronously, but I want them all done before continuing. Putting it in a transaction and rolling it back might make sense though... I'll have to give that a try.